# Django and Python 2.6

Tags: python, django

I'm just starting to get into Django, and of course as of last night one of the two new Python versions went final (2.6 obviously ;)) so I'm wondering if 2.6 plus Django is ready for actual use or do the Django team need more time to finish with tweaks/cleanup?

All the google searches I did were inconclusive, I saw bits about some initial test runs on beta 2 but nothing more recent seemed to show up.

Edit: http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/a48f81d916f24a04

They've confirmed here 1.0 w/2.6 works fine as far as they know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The impression I get is that 2.6 should work fine with Django 1.0. As found here: http://simonwillison.net/2008/Oct/2/whatus/

Answer (score 5):

Note that there is currently no python-mysql adapter for python2.6. If you need MySQL, stick with 2.5 for now.

Answer (score 2):

There is an unofficial build for mysqldb 1.2.2 win32 python 2.6 @ http://www.technicalbard.com/files/MySQL-python-1.2.2.win32-py2.6.exe